# What is the purpose of using serialVersionUID here?

Tags: java, serialversionuid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I bother about serialVersionUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid)

I was examining the Struts2 validation documentation. Even [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/basic-validation.html) it is defined:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7505437345373234225L;
```

What is the purpose of using serialVersionUID, how to use it(with random numbers?) and what is the purpose of using it at that documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `serialVersionUID` is an identifier for serialized objects. If the `serialVersionUID` of a serialized object doesn't match to the current `serialVersionUID` of that class, then the deserialization throws an `InvalidClassException`.
The UID is intended to be changed on every structural change of a class.